# Send SMS with Cordova

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, sms

The built-in [messaging app](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn_bS-vp7QAhVH1hoKHS9RBmwQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2Fmessaging-app&usg=AFQjCNHO8BlduV4fhwjyJaiebxB1DvYupA) in Ubuntu Touch has no commit since 2014, I would create a new one using Cordova.
Ubuntu Touch is supported by Cordova, but during plugin search I saw that sms plugin looks not work on Ubuntu Touch.

Is it possible to access SMS api with Cordova on Ubuntu Touch ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** The app seems maintained, but because of the lack of options and parameters, I'd develop my own application.

Comment: The messaging app is pretty much active I believe: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/messaging-app

Comment: Indeed I was wrong, I saw it [there](https://launchpad.net/messaging-app), but there is no much option etc, I would like contribute.